# Cannot understand Task Factory

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task

Please help me out with this, when running nothing is displayed

```
class Program
{
    public static void Write(string input, int times)
    {
        int i = 1000;
        while (i-- > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{input}  {i}");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Write("ABC", 10));
    }
}
```

Comment: you aren't waiting for the tasks to complete.

Comment: What is the purpose of `times` in your method? It appears to be ignored.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as needing more focus; it describes a clear problem that is not obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A C# console program ends when control leaves `Main`.  You said to start a worker to run a task and then control left `Main` before the worker actually ran. Workers do not keep a program alive; they are killed when the main thread is done.